# Dealing with nuanced 'Select All That Apply' question in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation, stringr, gsub

I'm trying to manipulate a column from a "Select All That Apply" Question. The entry, therefore, is different in length depending on the row/respondent. All but one ("Keeping Track of Time/Order") of the response options are followed by parentheses and a unique identifier for that response choice (see code below). To illustrate, I have two questions, one regarding strengths and one regarding challenges of a certain learning tool.

```
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:6, response_strength = c("Language (L) Attention (A)", "Movement Control (MC)", "Language (L) Getting Along with Others (G) Attention (A) Memory (M)", "Memory (M) Complex Thinking (C) Spatial Thinking (S)", "Memory (M) Spatial Thinking (S)", "Language (L) Attention (A)"), response_challenge = c("Movement Control (MC)", Language (L) Attention (A)", "Complex Thinking (C)", "Attention (A)", "Getting Along with Others (G) Keeping Track of Time/Order", "Keeping Track of Time/Order Movement Control (MC)"))
```

My goal is to convert to long format and have an output table that shows the percentage with which a given response option was chosen, like this: (*please note: the below code was created for illustration purposes so the percentages will not be accurate*)

```
df2 <- data.frame(survey_question = c("response_strength", "response_strength", "response_strength", "response_strength", "response_strength", "response_strength", "response_strength", "response_challenge", "response_challenge", "response_challenge", "response_challenge", "response_challenge", "response_challenge", "response_challenge"), response = c("Movement Control (MC)", "Language (L)", "Attention (A)", "Getting Along with Others (G)", "Complex Thinking (C)", "Spatial Thinking (S)","Keeping Track of Time/Order", "Movement Control (MC)", "Language (L)", "Attention (A)",                                                                                            "Getting Along with Others (G)", "Complex Thinking (C)", "Spatial Thinking (S)", "Keeping Track of Time/Order"), n = c(1, 2, 4, 5, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 5, 3, 1, 2),                                                                                     percent = c(.33, .67, 1.0, .33, .67, 1.0, .33, .67, 1.0, .33, .67, 1.0, .33, .67))
```

Output

```
survey_question                      response n percent
1   response_strength         Movement Control (MC) 1    0.33
2   response_strength                  Language (L) 2    0.67
3   response_strength                 Attention (A) 4    1.00
4   response_strength Getting Alone with Others (G) 5    0.33
5   response_strength          Complex Thinking (C) 3    0.67
6   response_strength          Spatial Thinking (S) 1    1.00
7   response_strength   Keeping Track of Time/Order 2    0.33
8  response_challenge         Movement Control (MC) 1    0.67
9  response_challenge                  Language (L) 2    1.00
10 response_challenge                 Attention (A) 4    0.33
11 response_challenge Getting Alone with Others (G) 5    0.67
12 response_challenge          Complex Thinking (C) 3    1.00
13 response_challenge          Spatial Thinking (S) 1    0.33
14 response_challenge   Keeping Track of Time/Order 2    0.67
```

I'm simply stuck on the best path forward. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Where in your code did you get stuck? If you edit your question to include the code, we can help troubleshoot. Good luck!

Comment: It's not that I got stuck it's that I don't know where to start. The code chunks are just to help the reader visualize the data I'm working with and how I want the output to look!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it, using look behinds, `pivot_longer()` and `mutate()`:

```
# load package
library(tidyverse)

# first, we make the response_strength and response_challenge columns longer, making a "question" and "response" column
# str_remove removes the "response_" bit at the beginning which serves no purpose
df |> pivot_longer(-ID, names_to = "question", values_to = "response", names_transform = \(x) str_remove(x, "response_")) |> 

  # next we split the values, looking behind for a closing bracket, or the word Order
  # Since this isn't your real data, you may have to edit this to make it work with the real code
  mutate(response = str_split(response, "(?<=\\)|Order) ")) |>

  # turn each response into it's own row
  unnest_longer(response) |>

  # create the n column and percent column
  mutate(n = n(), percent = n / sum(n), .by = c(ID, question))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 23 × 5
      ID question  response                          n percent
   <int> <chr>     <chr>                         <int>   <dbl>
 1     1 strength  Language (L)                      2    0.5 
 2     1 strength  Attention (A)                     2    0.5 
 3     1 challenge Movement Control (MC)             1    1   
 4     2 strength  Movement Control (MC)             1    1   
 5     2 challenge Language (L)                      2    0.5 
 6     2 challenge Attention (A)                     2    0.5 
 7     3 strength  Language (L)                      4    0.25
 8     3 strength  Getting Along with Others (G)     4    0.25
 9     3 strength  Attention (A)                     4    0.25
10     3 strength  Memory (M)                        4    0.25
# ℹ 13 more rows
```

Notes:

For more information on look behinds, you can read about them [here](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html).
Li